# meaning of a sentence 'Tables can be defined independently of the database'

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of "Tables can be defined independently of the database"

Comment: Shouldn't that question be rather on Stack Overflow???

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/q/204025/2886891 or http://searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/definition/database-agnostic

Comment: It would really, really help if you provided more context from where you found this. Asking about the meaning of a sentence without providing the rest of the paragraph is much like asking about the meaning of a word without providing the rest of the sentence. Ideally, you should not only include surrounding sentences, but also provide a link (if the full text is available online somewhere), or at least say where this came from: A news story? A technical manual? A comment in a computer program? A post from a message board? Knowing a source often helps people decipher the meaning of sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This is trying to say that you can define tables using database-independent definitions, such as those used for data types or lengths. This is commonly known as "database-agnostic".

You may read more about it e.g. here: [stackoverflow.com/q/204025/2886891](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204025/2886891)

I believe the sentence should have said: "tables can be defined, independent (or irrespective) of the database."

Answer (score 0):

This means that you can describe some tables and create them as in this database  as in some other databases.

Comment: What????????!!!?!